# TypeError: get_updates() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, api, bots, telegram

i'm trying to build a python telegram bot but I keep getting this error and i cant fint the source of the error...
details:

My Class:

```
class weed4us_bot():
    def __init__(self, config):
        self.token = self.read_token_from_config_file(config)
        self.base = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot{}/'.format(self.token)

    def get_updates(self, offset=None):
        url = self.base + 'getUpdates?timeout=100'
        if offset:
            url = url + '&offset={}'.format(offset + 1)
        r = requests.get(url)
        return json.loads(r.content)

    def send_massage(self, msg, chat_id):
        url = self.base + 'sendMessage?chat_id={}&text={}'.format(chat_id, msg)
        if msg is not None:
            requests.get(url)

def read_token_from_config_file(config):
    parser = cfg.ConfigParser()
    parser.read(config)
    return parser.get('creds', 'token')
```

My Main file:

```
from main_bot import weed4us_bot as bot

update_id = None

def make_reply(msg):
    if msg is not None:
        reply = 'okay'
        return reply


while True:
    print('...')
    updates = bot.get_updates(offset=update_id)
    updates = updates['result']
    if updates:
        for item in updates:
            update_id = item['update_id']
            try:
                message = item['message']['text']
            except:
                message = None
            from_ = item['message']['from']['id']
            reply = make_reply(message)
            bot.send_massage(reply, From_)
```

and I keep getting this error:

> TypeError: get_updates() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 2):

`get_updates` is a method from class `weed4us_bot` so if you want to call this method, you need to call it on an object of this class. So first you need to create an object of class: `obj = weed4us_bot()`, and then call this method `obj.get_updates(offset=update_id)`.

There is also a second possible way to call this method: `weed4us_bot.get_updates(object, offset=update_id)` but still you need to create an object of this class.

Your error occurs in this line: `updates = bot.get_updates(offset=update_id)`. To fix it you could first create object of class weed4us_bot: `bot_object = bot(some_config)` and then call method on object: `bot_object.get_updates(offset=update_id)`. Or pass `weed4us_bot` object as self. You can do it in this way: `bot.get_updates(bot(some_config), offset=update_id)`